# C do{} while(function(argumen)==1) in I/O FILES

Tags: c

So i need to enter ID(int)(it has to be a 3 digit format) argument and make a check function if there is same ID in FILE datoteka.txt that i made.
Thanks for help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
struct struktura{
    int ID;
    char imeprezime[20];
    int placa;
    int godina;
};

int clear_input_buffer(void) {
    int ch;
    while (((ch = getchar()) != EOF) && (ch != '\n')) /* void */;
    return ch;
}
```

ID check :cant get it to return flag = 1;

```
//function that should check if there is same ID as the one you enter
//returning 1 if there is same ID or 0 if there is not
int provjera(int IDprovjera){
    int flag=0;
    int datID;
    FILE *datprovjera = NULL;
    datprovjera = fopen("datoteka.txt","r");
    if(datprovjera == NULL){
        printf("Nema datoteke!");
        exit(2);
    }
    while(fscanf(datprovjera,"%d#%[^#]#%d#%d#",&datID)==4){
        if (datID == IDprovjera){
            flag=1;
            break;
        }

    }
    fclose(datprovjera);
    return flag;
}
```

Main

```
int main()
{
    int i,M;
    int provjera_2;

  struct struktura radnik;

  FILE *datoteka = NULL;
  datoteka = fopen("datoteka.txt","w");
  if (datoteka == NULL){
    printf("Greska!");
    exit(1);
  }
    printf("Unesi broj radnika:\n");
    scanf("%d",&M);
    for(i=0;i<M;i++){
            //ID
            do{
                do{
                printf("Unesi ID\n");
                scanf("%d",&radnik.ID);
                clear_input_buffer();
                }while(
                       provjera(radnik.ID)!=0);

            }while(
                   radnik.ID/100>9 || radnik.ID/100<1);
                fprintf(datoteka,"%d",radnik.ID);
                fprintf(datoteka,"%c",'#');

            //Ime Prezime
            printf("Unesi ime i prezime radnika:\n");
            gets(radnik.imeprezime);
            fprintf(datoteka,"%s",radnik.imeprezime);
            fprintf(datoteka,"%c",'#');

            //Placa
            printf("Unesi placu radnika:\n");
            scanf("%d",&radnik.placa);
            fprintf(datoteka,"%d",radnik.placa);
            fprintf(datoteka,"%c",'#');

            //Godine
            do{
                printf("Unesi godinu pocetka rada:\n");
                scanf("%d",&radnik.godina);
                clear_input_buffer();
            }while(
                   radnik.godina<1970 || radnik.godina>2016);
            fprintf(datoteka,"%d",radnik.godina);
            fprintf(datoteka,"%c\n",'#');
        }
    fclose(datoteka);
```

Comment: What values does `datID` take on when reading the file? What are the contents of the file? What's an example value for `IDprovjera`? (@DevSolar - That advice seems unnecessary. The code is clear regardless of the variable names, the comments are in English.)

Comment: `while(provjera(radnik.ID)!=0);` seems to be *ignoring* a match.

Comment: @WeatherVane - That's not an empty `while` loop; it's the end of a `do..while` loop that has a non-empty body (and hence is not ignoring the match).

Comment: @TedHopp I can see that: but he is looping as long as a match was found.

Comment: datID should take first %d(ID that has been entered before) from the file datoteka.txt and compare it with newly entered ID

Comment: @WeatherVane - Ah, yes. So the problem may be that the function is _always_ returning 1 yet insisting that another ID be entered. OP thinks the function never returns 1, but that may not be the problem at all.

Comment: @TedHopp: I disagree.

Comment: @DevSolar - With what? I hope you aren't disagreeing that the comments are in English (they are). Or perhaps that variable names don't need to be in English? Would you complain if the variables were named `x`, `y`, etc.? See [this thread in Meta])http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254734/foreign-variable-names-etc-in-code).

Comment: @TedHopp: I raise your one English comment by three non-English ones. And while this example here, or any other piece of code, may or may not be legible with localized identifiers, I consider the recommendation to prefer English identifiers quite valid, not unnecessary. And I disagree with whoever deleted my comment just because he disagreed.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: @DevSolar - Your comment was probably deleted by a moderator for being non-constructive (as is this entire comment sub-thread). For the record, I didn't flag your comment.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet in `provjera` has a few issues:

```
while(fscanf(datprovjera,"%d#%[^#]#%d#%d#",&datID)==4){
```

Your format string specifies that you want to read 4 parameters (4 `%`), but you only pass in 1. I suspect `fscanf` is either returning 1 or has set an error on the file (which you can retrieve with `ferror(datprojvera)`).

Comment: Good catch: not providing enough arguments will cause *undefined behaviour*.